# Corrupt SD-card on embedded linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded-linux, ext3

I'm working on an EmbeddedArm TS-7553 ARM device, running a 2.6.24 Linux.
I'm developing on an Ubuntu 14.04 32bit  virtual VirtualBux guest.

I downloaded their SD-card image (2gbsd-noeclipse-mar292017.dd), constructed of 3 partitions.
Writing the image (with dd) works fine, no visible errors.

I then update the ext3 filesystem:
 1. I loop-mount the FS partition:

```
  sudo mount -orw,loop,offset=$((24260*512)) ./Image.dd ./FS
```

2. I update the FS (copying a bunch of dirs and files, adding symlinks)
 3. I umount the partition

I then dd the updated image to the SD-card and boot the embedded device:

- dmesg shows errors:

  ```
  EXT3-fs error (device nbd9): htree_dirblock_to_tree: bad entry in directory #10056: rec_len % 4 != 0 - offset=8192, inode=1838169323, rec_len=25707, name_len=111
  ```
- Files are missing (**mawk, in /usr/bin/**, for example)

**This behavior is constant, after many attempts...**
**If I insert the SD-card to my Ubuntu - the missing mawk file exists...**

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Posted in Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, thanks, shouldn't have defaulted to here...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a legacy call to a built-in utility (`sdctl -P`) too early in my startup script.
Removing the call fixed the issue.